# Consultar Datos a partir de un Dato Ingresado C++

Tags: c++

Buenas Tardes, tengo un ejercicio en el que al principio pido el Nombre y Cédula de una Persona, los almaceno en un vector y corre el programa, con otros cálculos que hago. **El caso es que al final** desarrolle un menú con varias opciones, una de ellas es La lista de todas esas personas con sus nombres y cedulas, **la otra opcion es que a partir de una cedula (dato que pedi al principio), me muestre los datos de esa persona**.

*El codigo donde pido los datos*

```
for (i = 0; i < 2; i++)
{
    system("cls");
    total_mensual[i] = 0;
    sueldo_mensual[i] = 0;
    seguro[i] = 0;
    bono_mensual[i] = 0;
    sueldo_semana_total[i] = 0;
    cout<<"< = = = = = F A B R I C A de F O R R O S para V E H I C U L O S = = = = = >";
    cout<<"\n\nIngrese el Nombre del Trabajador: "<<i<<". ";
    cin>>nombre[i];
    cout<<"\nCedula del Trabajador: ";
    cin>>cedula[i];
```

*La parte del menu donde quiero que con la cedula que ingrese me arroje los datos*

```
case 2:

        system("cls");
        cout<<"< = = = = = F A B R I C A de F O R R O S para V E H I C U L O S = = = = = >";
        cout<<"\n\nOpcion 2: Consulta de Datos por Cedula";
        cout<<"\n\nIngrese el Numero de Cedula: ";
        //Aqui ingreso la cedula, y luego deberia arrojarme los datos de la persona (nombre y cedula).
        break;
```

Comment: Ya tienes 7 preguntas en tu haber... ¿cual es la pregunta? ¿que te hagamos el ejercicio?

Comment: No quiero que me hagan el Ejercicio, el ejercicio ya esta casi hecho. La duda es como hago que segun un dato que ingrese antes, como hago para luego consultar los datos de esa persona a partir de la cedula, que fue un dato que di anteriormente.

Comment: Esa parte te falta en la pregunta. ¿No has intentado buscar el dato de ninguna forma?

Comment: Para ello estoy preguntando, como se hace para consultar los datos de una persona a partir de la cedula.

Comment: el caso es que las preguntas no solo sirven para ayudarte a tí sino también a cualquiera con una duda similar. Eso te obliga a redactar una pregunta lo más completa y correcta posible. Es el precio a pagar para que te dediquemos nuestro tiempo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solo itera dentro de tu Array hasta que encuentres un valor de la cédula que corresponda con el valor ingresado

```
cin>>cedulaingresada;
for (i = 0; i < 2; i++)
{
    if (cedulaingresada== cedula[i]) { 
           cout << total_mensual[i] << endl;
           cout << sueldo_mensual[i] << endl;
            //etcetera

    }

}
```

Comment: Gracias pana, asi lo estaba haciendo pero olvide el for, ya que se trataba de un vector.                  Tengo otra pregunta, como haria lo mismo pero para modificar los datos?.

Comment: `cin>>total_mensual[i];`